# javascript document.getElementById Loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this print out the grades in the array that I created. I can get my *for* loop to cycle through all of the grades in the array but it only prints out the last grade. I have it set up to print the grade out each time the *for* loop completes one cycle, but as I said, it is only printing out the last grade. I also tried to use the `.innerHTML` but that did not work either as you will see in the code:

```js
var arrayTest = [78, 65, 41, 99, 100, 81];
var arrayLength = arrayTest.length;
var midtermTest = 60;
var msg = "";
var grade;

arrayOfGrades();
addBonus();

function tellGrade() {
    if (grade > 100) {
        msg = "Grade is higher than 100!, " + grade;
    }
    else if (grade >= 90) {
        msg = "You got an A " + grade + "!!, ";
    }
    else if (grade >= 80) {
        msg = "You got a B " + grade + "!!, ";
    }
    else if (grade >= 70) {
        msg = "You got a C " + grade + "!!, ";
    }
    else if (grade >= 60) {
        msg = "You got a D " + grade + "!!, ";
    }
    else if (grade <= 59) {
        msg = "You got a F " + grade + "!! :(, ";
    }
    else if (grade < 0) {
        msg = "Grade is less than 0, " + grade;
    }
}

function arrayOfGrades() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        grade = arrayTest[i];
        tellGrade(grade);
        writeGrade();
    }
}
function addBonus()
{
    midtermTest = midtermTest + (midtermTest * .05);
    grade = midtermTest;
    tellGrade(grade);
    writeMidtermGrade();
}

function writeGrade() {
    //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Test grade letter: " + msg.toString() + "<br />";
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    el.textContent = "Test grade letter: " + msg.toString();
}


function writeMidtermGrade() {
    var el = document.getElementById('midterm');
    el.textContent = "Midterm test grade letter: " + msg.toString();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DecisionsAndLoopsAssignment1_Byrd</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Missing grade!!</div>
    <div id="midterm">Missing grade!!</div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are replacing the element content `el.textContent = "Test grade letter: " + msg.toString();` not appending. use `el.textContent +=` istead

Comment: @Searching Thank you, that fixed my issue. Do you know of a way to make it print on the next line for each grade? While still using the el.textContect?

Comment: To print multiple lines, you can try using el.innerHTML += msg.toString() + " <br>"; instead

Comment: answer by rposborne is good and as EmadSalah mentioned for multi lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the ENTIRE content of the element not just adding on to it.  This will constantly overwrite the work of the previous iteration of the loop, therefore you will only see the last result, cause computers are fast.

You have two options, read the textContent of the element, and continue adding to it. This concept is called self assignment.

```
var aMessage = "Hello, ";
aMessage += "World!";
console.log(aMessage") // => "Hello, World!"
```

Though general we would create a new element and append that element as a child

```js
var msg = "A+"; // this should be a variable to our function vs a global va

function writeGrade() {
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    var newEl = document.createElement("p");
    newEl.textContent = "Test grade letter: " + msg.toString();
    el.appendChild(newEl)
}

writeGrade()
```

```html
<div id="test"> 

</div>
```

Comment: Does that mean that I would have to go and write a new element child for each grade that I write? I don't believe I have ever dealt with appending or element child(s) before in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

function writeGrade() overwrites whatever might already by in the  elements it outputs to.  So when called more than once only the last value is preserved.  Using .innerHTML would do the same thing.  Accumulating the content strings to a single var then making a single call to output them is one option to fix this.

I also note that you're passing temporary values around in global vars, which is generally considered poor form.

Comment: Could please explain more on the last sentence. I would say that i am still new to JavaScript but I could be wrong. So I am still have a lot to learn.

Comment: That's a side issue that goes beyond the scope of the original question.  In short, using local variables, function parameters, and return values makes it a lot easier to not trip over yourself as the code gets longer.